# How to show the from onclick of button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here is my form:

```
<form ng-show="skm" class="form-inline editable-wrap editable-text ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" role="form">
    <input type="text" ng-model="doc" placeholder="Field:">
    <button type="submit">Ok</button>
</form>
```

And I want to show this `form` when I `click` on the `button` given below:

```
<a tooltip="Add more" href="javascript:void(0);" class="plus" ng-model ="skm"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
```

Comment: <a tooltip="Add more" href="javascript:void(0);" class="plus" ng-model ="skm" ng-click="skm = !skm"> ....

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to use with the controller's function then this is one option for you
set your module and controller like this..

```
angular.module("my_app",[]) 
    .controller("my_ctr",function($scope){
        $scope.skm=false;
        $scope.mmmmmm=function()
        {       
            if($scope.skm==false)
            {
                $scope.skm=true;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.skm=false;
            }
        }
    })


<body ng-app="my_app" ng-controller="my_ctr">
<button ng-click="mmmmmm()">hii</button>    
<form ng-model="frm" ng-show="skm" class="form-inline editable-wrap editable-text ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" role="form">
    <input type="text" ng-model="doc" placeholder="Field:">
    <button type="submit">Ok</button>
</form> 
</body>
```

I hope your doubt is clear.

Answer (score 0):

What you are refering to is ngShow and ngHide

**Read this article**

[ngShow and ngHide tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/how-to-use-ngshow-and-nghide)

```
<div ng-app>
    <a tooltip="Add more" ng-click="showForm = !showForm" href="javascript:void(0);" class="plus" ng-model="skm" >
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    </a>

    <form ng-show="showForm" class="form-inline editable-wrap editable-text ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" role="form">
        <input type="text" ng-model="doc" placeholder="Field:">
        <button type="submit">Ok</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/abayq292/

Comment: using this code my form is hide but when i click on add more button to show the from but form is not showing.

Comment: Do you have your code in ng-app?  This is working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/abayq292/